# How to solve the type error while sorting in react with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, typescript1.8, tablesort

I Am trying to sort a table with the list which is retrieving through API. I am doing this in react + typescript. I am facing the type error. Kindly, help me. Below is my code. 
So by hovering on Name , Type , Color  this should sort  but sorting is not working. kindly go through the code and help me do sorting .

```
export interface VehicleListProps {
    vehicle: VehicleState;

    listVehicles: (limit: number, skip: number) => void;
    addVehicle: (id: string) => void;
    deleteVehicle: (id: string, limit: number, skip: number) => void;
}

const Row = ({name, type , color }) => (
  <div className="row">
    <div>{name}</div>
    <div>{type}</div>
    <div>{color}</div>

  </div>
);

const VehicleList: React.FC<VehicleListProps> = (props) => {

    constructor(props); {
      this.state = {
        data: vehicle

};


     this.compareBy = compareBy.bind(this);
     this.sortBy = sortBy.bind(this);
    }

    function compareBy(key) {
      return function (a, b) {
        if (a[key] < b[key]) return -1;
        if (a[key] > b[key]) return 1;
        return 0;
      };
    }

  function  sortBy(key) {
      let vehicle = [...this.state.data];
      vehicle.sort(this.compareBy(key));
      this.setState({data: vehicle});
    }

    const rows = this.state.data.map( (rowData) => <Row {...rowData} />);

    return (

        <div>  

          <div className="row gap-20 masonry pos-r">
              <Table id="dataTable" className="table table-hover table-striped">
                  <thead className="thead-dark" >
                      <tr>
                          <th onClick={() => this.sortBy('name')}>Name</th>
                          <th onClick={() => this.sortBy('type')}>Type</th>                     
                          <th onClick={() => this.sortBy('color')}>Color</th>         
                          <th></th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>{
                      vehicle.page.collection.map((vehicle, idx) => {
                          return (
                              <tr key={idx}>
                                  <td><a className="vehicleName" href={`/vehicles/${vehicle.id}`}>{vehicle.name}</a></td>
                                  <td>{vehicle.type}</td>

                                  <td>{vehicle.color}</td>

                              </tr>
                          )
                      })
                  }</tbody>

              </Table>


              </div>

          </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Add the complete error you are getting.

Comment: ERROR :::  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Comment: this.compareBy is undefined so you are getting this error, to know what is causing this error more details are required, the code you have provided is not enough.

Comment: kindly see my updated code once

Comment: Same error! cannot read property bind

Comment: compareBy and sortBy are not methods of the class, assuming they are in scope you can do: `this.compareBy = compareBy.bind(this);
     this.sortBy = sortBy.bind(this);`

Comment: Thanks , HMR error got resolved but again am facing error in const rows = this.state.data.map( (rowData) => <Row {...rowData} />);     {Typr error:  this.state.data.map is not a function}

Comment: Kindly go through my full updated code. By hovering on name the table should sort but its not woking.